# My uitableview.delegate is getting set to null. Any ideas why, or how I can figure out why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I presume this isn't a common problem, which makes it a bit more difficult to answer. Any help is appreciated though.

I need to call this delegate a number of times in my app, and i noticed that after a number of times, the delegate starts to come back as NULL (and hence stops responding). I put an nslog everywhere the delegate gets called, so i know that at this point, it's fine:

```
UIImage *image = [self.delegate largeThumnailForMediaAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Then the next time this line gets called, the delegate is set to NULL. No lines around it call or set the delegate. I put an NSLog on the setDelegate method too, and that didn't get called before it changed to NULL.

Any code you might need to see, let me know. Any ideas you want me to try out, let me know about that too.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Bizarre, but might help to lead to a solution. I put an NSTimer scheduledTimer.. in the class which gets made the delegate, and got it to fire that once a second so I could see if it turned null at any point. The result i got, however, was that this time it didn't turn null. It returned all of the delegate methods. When i took the timer out, it goes back to returning NULL. Obviously having a timer in there is an odd workaround 'solution'. I'm hoping this rings a bell for someone and gives them a clue to where the problem might lie?

EDIT 2: I've solved this problem by, instead of using this code in my AppDelegate:

```
JCreateViewController *create = [[JCreateViewController alloc] init];
    [create.navigationBar addLeftButtonWithTitle:@"Back" type:JButtonTypeArrow];
   create.navigationBar.title = @"Entry #17";
    [self.window addSubview:create.view];
```

Declaring it in my header file, then using this:

```
self.create = [[JCreateViewController alloc] init];
    [self.create.navigationBar addLeftButtonWithTitle:@"Back" type:JButtonTypeArrow];
    self.create.navigationBar.title = @"Entry #17";
    [self.window addSubview:self.create.view];
```

I don't understand why this makes a difference though. I'd love to know, if anybody does know?

Comment: How do you "set" the delegate?

Comment: `self.tableView.delegate = self;`

Comment: If you've implemented `-setDelegate:` and that's not getting called, then are you using ARC and is your `delegate` declared as `weak`? If so, it will become `nil` automatically when the actual object gets deallocated.

Comment: Maybe Instance of your class is getting deallocated ? Hard to tell from your question. Place a breakpoint in your dealloc method (assuming this is non-ARC code)

Comment: Andrew, you've now confused me. Your code sample shows `self.delegate`, which implies it's a custom delegate on your object, but you're saying the problem is actually your `UITableView`'s `delegate`?

Comment: And how is your delegate declared on the class that declares the protocol? Possible reference problem, class that owns delegate property getting cleaned up as it's reference count is zero.

Comment: @KevinBallard It's referenced as .tableview.delegate, but it's not actually a UITableView, it's a view.

Comment: @PeterKelly I'm unsure which code you want me to post. You want me to post the code that starts with `@protocol` through to `@end`?

Comment: You're using ARC? Looks like nothing owns the controller. The timer retains its target and is itself retained by the run loop, so, yes, that would keep this object alive. In your last snippet, what's `self`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're using ARC. Whatever this object is, nothing owns it. Nothing has a strong reference to it, so it gets released, and then at some point it gets deallocated.

```
JCreateViewController *create = [[JCreateViewController alloc] init];
```

This is a local variable. When the variable goes out of scope at the end of the method, you can't access that object anymore. Under MRR, this would be a leak. Under ARC, the object is going to die, just like it was in an autorelease pool.

```
self.create = [[JCreateViewController alloc] init];
```

By creating a property (presumably `strong`) and putting the controller into that property, you've given whatever `self` is an owning reference to the controller. It will now live as long as the property isn't reassigned or set to `nil`.

The timer fixed things because the timer retains its target (which I believe was the controller (your question is rather unclear)), and the timer itself is retained by the run loop. So the run loop keeps the repeating timer alive and the timer kept your controller alive.

In short, make sure something owns this object and it'll stick around.